# why is it trying to convert? c#

Tags: c#, foreach, double

i have two 'foreach' loops that are throwing errors telling me that i cannot convert Student.FoodItem to a double. I'm stumped as to what I have done wrong, here are the loops.

```
 foreach (double cost in Order.OrderedFood)
        {
            totalFood += Food.Cost;
        }

 foreach (double cost in Order.OrderedDrink)
        {
            totalDrink += Drink.Cost;
        }

 double totalFood = 0.0;
 double totalDrink = 0.0;
```

Comment: What is the type of totalDrink?

Comment: And why are you iterating over the collections when you're not using their values?

Comment: WHERE IS FOOD ITEM IN THIS CODE?

Comment: I would like to recommend to study a bit before doing your class assignment.

Answer (score 3):

This could be done more elegantly using LINQ:

```
totalFood = Order.OrderedFood.Sum(x => x.Cost);
totalDrink = Order.OrderedDrink.Sum(x => x.Cost);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you've declared your iterator variable as a `double`. You probably meant something like this:

```
foreach (FoodItem food in Order.OrderedFood)
{
    totalFood += food.Cost;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first loop should be something like:

```
foreach (FoodItem foodItem in Order.OrderedFood)
{
    totalFood += foodItem.Cost;
}
```

You're looping through a collection of FoodItems, not a collection of costs.